# Timeout issues with Python itertools.combinations()

Tags: python, python-itertools

We've got a script that uses `itertools.combinations()` and it seems to hang with a large input size.

I'm a relatively inexperienced Python programmer so I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Is there a more suitable library? Or is there a way to enable verbose logging to that I can debug why the method call is hanging?

Any help is much appreciated.

[Edit]

```
def findsubsets(S,m):
    return set( itertools.combinations(S, m) )

for s in AllSearchTerms:
    S.append(itemsize)
    itemsize = itemsize + 1

for i in range (1,6):
    Subset = findsubsets(S,i)
    for sub in Subset:
        for s in sub:
            sublist.append(AllSearchTerms[s])
        PComb.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
```

Comment: `itertools.combinations(..)` itself is **lazy**. So it depends on **what the consumer does with the output**...

Comment: As the previous comment states, the consequences depend on what you do with the returned value from `itertools.combinations()`. If you need more help, show us a code snippet that shows what you do with the result and the resulting hang. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, the number of combinations [may be _huge;_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficients_as_polynomials) your algorithm may be correct, just working for longer than you expect.

Comment: Thanks WillemVanOnsem and @RoryDaulton. I've updated the question with the code snippet. Is that enough to be useful?

Comment: @9000 that's true. Is there a way to get a counter or some kind of logging information? So that I know whether it's stuck or whether it's just taking a long time

Comment: Well, [fundamentally](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) it scales pretty horrifically.

Comment: Why in the world are you materializing the `combinations` iterator into a `set`? That certainly adds a useless pass over your data. It doesn't affect the complexity, but you are adding a big fat 2 to your constant factors...

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. It's probably not required. I'll look into refactoring that to remove the useless pass.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things in your code that will hang for large input sizes.

First, your function `findsubsets` calls `itertools.combinations` then converts the result to a set. The result of `itertools.combinations` is a generator, yielding each combination one at a time without storing them or all calculating them all at once. When you convert that to a set, you force Python to calculate and store them all at once. Therefore the line `return set( itertools.combinations(S, m) )` is almost certainly where your program hangs. You can check that by placing print statements (or some other kind of logging statements) immediately before and after that line, and if you see the preceding print and the program hangs before you see the succeeding one, you have found the problem. The solution is not to convert the combinations to a set. Leave it as a generator, and your program can grab one combination at a time, as needed.

Second, even if you do what I just suggested, your loop `for sub in Subset:` is a fairly tight loop that uses every combination. If the input size is large, that loop will take a very long time and implementing my previous paragraph will not help. You probably should reorganize your program to avoid the large input sizes, or at least show some kind of progress during that loop. The combinations function [has a predictable output size](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) so you can even show the percent done in a progress bar.

There is no logging inside `itertools.combinations` since it is not needed when used properly, and there is no logging in the conversion of the generator to a set. You can implement logging in your own tight loop, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Rory. Yes you are exactly right - I've already put log statements in and can confirm that `return set( itertools.combinations(S, m) )` is where it's hanging. I'll try your suggested solution to see if it fixes the problem. I'll test this out and upvote if it works :)